# Irreducibility of a polynomial with integer coefficients on the complex field

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to understand the solution of the problem 4.
https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2001/prob_sol1.pdf

My question is, $q(x) = 1+x+....+x^n$ is reducible on the complex field, so why can't $r(x)$ be expressed as the product of two polynomials with complex coefficients?, one of the them a factor of $q(x)$, so that we can have $r(x)$ with some roots of $q(x)$, but not all of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Over $\mathbb C[X]$ every polynomial with degree larger than $1$ is reducible. Are you sure it is not about reducibility over $\mathbb Q[X]$ ?

Comment: Hi! Yes, that's what I don't understand. In the sentence of the problem, there's no restriction about which field to take, so why we couldn't take Q(X)?

Comment: In the problem, the coefficients of the polynomial are all in $\mathbb Q$. So the point is that the this polynomial having the primitive $q$-th roots of unity among its roots is a package deal. Either it contains all of them or none of them because the primitive $q$-th roots of unity are all conjugate to each other. The reason for this is that the minimal polynomial of the primitive $q$-th root of unity over the rationals must divide any other polynomial that this root of unity satisfies. But the minimal polynomial precisely packages all the other primitive $q$-th roots of unity.

Comment: ***Any other polynomial defined over $\mathbb Q$. This is a key detail I missed.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I completely got it now!